# Any way to get Twitter user email?

Tags: api, rest, facebook, twitter

Is there any way to get Twitter user email from Twitter API?

Facebook (FBQL) provides this data in the hashed form so that you can encrypt email and then compare to the hashed one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. If the user wants email from someone, they set that up through the DM settings.  That's kind of the point.

You could setup a friendship, and set DMs to email the user.

[Twitter API - Create Friendship](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-friendships%C2%A0create)

Comment: Not a solution for me, I want to get exactly email address (hashed or anythinged...) and compare it with another email. 

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I assume you have the user credentials?  If you don't twitter will(should) never let you get that information.  Spammers would kill for a list like that :)  If you do, you might look into doing some screen scraping.