# get user email from twitter framework in ios

Tags: ios6, twitter, ios5.1

i am using Twitter framework (iOS-5 and iOS-6 ) to get user details but i need user email id to be able to log in in my system. I have seen many post regarding this like

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us?lq=1)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372797/any-way-to-get-twitter-user-email)

and i have also checked twitter reverse api [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth)

but it is giving me only auth tokens.

Can someone please confirm me that we can't get user email from twitter or i am not been able to figure it out. Already i have wasted my lots of time searching for this please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can't get user email from Twitter.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation Evgeny.

Comment: Yo can get it. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get Email from Twitter now.

1. First you need to get permission to access user-email from Twitter. In order to do that fill out this [form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform). Ask for special permission and permission required is 'Email'. Once Twitter grants permission(They will send an email regarding this), goto next step.
2. Please follow this link from Fabric: [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/request-user-email-address.html)

// Objective-C

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController = [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc] initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"Email %@, Error: %@", email, error);
    }];
    [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
  // TODO: Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
}
```

// Swift

```
if Twitter.sharedInstance().session {
  let shareEmailViewController = TWTRShareEmailViewController() { email, error in
    println("Email \(email), Error: \(error)")
  }
  self.presentViewController(shareEmailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
  // TODO: Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now **possible** using Fabric SDK and [these steps](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/request-email)